# Select specified items from rows at first priority mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table `users`

```
id | Name |
1    John 
2    Dwayne
3    Daniel
4    Ronaldo
5    Messi
6    Gareth
7    Leonardo
8    Brad
```

If i have id's in order of `(7,5,1,3)` and i want to select `limit 6` then the expected output should be as following :-

```
id  Name 
7 | Leonardo
5 | Messi
1 | John 
3 | Daniel
2 | Dwayne
4 | Ronaldo
```

What i did previously was this but did not get the expected output . Help!!

```
"select * from users ORDER BY FIELD(user_id,7,5,1,3) LIMIT 6"
```

Comment: what are u using to create the order of `7,5,1,3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close.  It just doesn't take into account all the *other* user ids.  Try this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(user_id,7,5,1,3) > 0 desc,
         FIELD(user_id,7,5,1,3)
LIMIT 6;
```

The problem with your version is that `field()` returns `0` when there is no match.  And the `0`s will be ordered first.

Comment: wow it works Thanks But can you explain a bit what happened there @gordon

Comment: I thought I did.  When you just use `field()`, the function returns 0 for non-matching rows -- and these will go first in an ascending sort.